# ExoPlayer, generalize SimpleCache behaviour

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using ExoPlayer 2 to play music from the web. Now I want to cache downloaded music by using the beautiful `SimpleCache` class. My problem is the following: every time I request to play a song, the server returns me a different URL (also for the same song), which is used as key by `SimpleCache`. Consequently, `SimpleCache` creates a new cache file for each URL (i.e. also a different file for the same song).

It would be nice if there was a way to ask me what is the key of the cached file generated for a particular url. Do you know a way to do that?

The `SimpleCache` class is `final`, so I cannot override its methods.

**EDIT, a rough solution:**
I created a copy of `CacheDataSource` and changed just this line in the method `open(DataSpec)`, which is responsible of keys' generation:

```
key = dataSpec.key != null ? dataSpec.key : uri.toString();
```

I could generate the same key thanks to some `uri`'s parameters which are equals for each url retrieved for the same song. This solution solves my problem but is not so generic and exploitable for every possible case.

The `CacheDataSource` has been then used as explained in [this comment](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/420#issuecomment-244652023):

```
private DataSource.Factory buildDataSourceFactory(final boolean useBandwidthMeter) {
    return new DataSource.Factory() {
        @Override
        public DataSource createDataSource() {
            LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor evictor = new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(100 * 1024 * 1024);
            SimpleCache simpleCache = new SimpleCache(new File(getCacheDir(), "media_cache"), evictor);
            return new CacheDataSource(
                simpleCache,
                buildMyDataSourceFactory(useBandwidthMeter).createDataSource(),
                CacheDataSource.FLAG_BLOCK_ON_CACHE,
                10 * 1024 * 1024
            );
        }
    };
}

private DefaultDataSource.Factory buildMyDataSourceFactory(boolean useBandwidthMeter) {
    return new DefaultDataSourceFactory(PlayerActivity.this, userAgent, useBandwidthMeter ? BANDWIDTH_METER : null);
}
```

Comment: upvoting this question, as the internet lacks resources on it, ie caching using exo player!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ExoPlayer 2.10.0 it has been added the `ProgressiveMediaSource` class, which replaces the `ExtractorMediaSource` (deprecated).
When creating a ProgressiveMediaSource with its `Factory` class you can call the method `setCustomCacheKey(String)`.

It exactly does what I needed!

Comment: key must be unique which we are passing to setCustomCachekey()?

Comment: I think yes. Having the same key for two streams wouldn't have sense. Doc says `Sets the custom key that _uniquely_ identifies the original stream.`

Comment: @Massimo this method is deprecated now. What is the alternative solution to this? The CacheDataSource.Factory has setCacheKeyFactory(CacheKeyFactory cacheKeyFactory)  but CacheKeyFactory is only interface.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution (works on exoplayer 2.10.2 not sure for earlier versions).
To create your source:

```
DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                Util.getUserAgent(context, getString(R.string.app_name)));

 CacheDataSourceFactory cacheDataSourceFactory =
                new CacheDataSourceFactory(downloadUtil.getDownloadCache(context), dataSourceFactory,
                        new FileDataSourceFactory(),
                        new CacheDataSinkFactory(downloadUtil.getDownloadCache(context), CacheDataSink.DEFAULT_FRAGMENT_SIZE),
                        0,null,new CacheKeyProvider());

ProgressiveMediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(your_uri);
```

where `CacheKeyProvider()` is your own implementation of `CacheKeyFactory`. This class will define what will be used as the key. Mine looks like this:

```
public class CacheKeyProvider implements CacheKeyFactory 
{

    @Override
    public String buildCacheKey(DataSpec dataSpec) {
        if (dataSpec.key!=null) return dataSpec.key;
        else return generate_key(dataSpec.uri);
    }

    private String generate_key(Uri uri){
        String string = uri.toString();
        String[] parts = string.split("\\?");
        String part1 = parts[0];
        String part2 = parts[1];
        return part1;
    }
}
```

In my case I'm retreiving whatever doesn't change when my url changes and using that as the key.

Comment: `CacheDataSourceFactory` is deprecated and is altered by `CacheDataSource.Factory`, and in its constructor already initialize the  `cacheKeyFactory = CacheKeyFactory.DEFAULT`. But I don't understand the expression in `CacheKeyFactory`, `CacheKeyFactory DEFAULT = (dataSpec) -> dataSpec.key != null ? dataSpec.key : dataSpec.uri.toString();`
What is the `dataSpec` here? How to input the `dataSpec` in `CacheKeyFactory`. And if we use `CacheKeyProvider` as the input of `CacheDataSource.Factory`, how it could change the value of `cacheKeyFactory` that is assigned to `CacheKeyFactory.DEFAULT`.

Comment: @neo have you found solution ?